# How exactly do crowd-controlling abilities work?

Tags: diablo-iii

There are the usual kinds of crowd-controlling abilities in Diablo III: Stunning, rooting, snaring, charm, hex, fear etc.

It appears like some monsters are less affected by them than others. It seems, however, that even bosses can be, for example, frozen.

How exactly do CCs work? Do they have diminishing returns, like in WoW? Are all bosses equally CCable? Is CC efficiency or chance of successful CCing in any way dependant on any attribute (e.g. chance to fear enemies)?

The answer of this question will have some important implications for boss-fights in general, but especially for groups. If there are, for example, no diminishing returns on stuns, then four-player parties could easily specialize in stunning-equipment and skills to kill a boss without the boss hitting anyone even once.

Some monsters also have crowd-controlling abilities. What stats prevent me from being CCed (stunned, feared, snared, etc.) by enemies?

Comment: Each mob seems to work differently, with varying diminishing returns from each skill.

Comment: As a Witch Doctor, my "Mass Confusion" (read: MC) spell surprisingly affects most bosses. There a few it doesn't, and I don't know why, because for the most part, I can charm/MC any boss I like. I'd imagine they will fix this; charming a boss removes any of it's defense mechanisms for the duration.

Comment: That's interesting. I mean... I hear that bosses aren't that hard on Inferno anyways (the hardest enemies are supposedly the champion packs or yellow elite monsters), but even for those, crowd controlling builds in groups must be pretty damn powerful, if there are no diminishing returns at all.

Answer (score 1):

To partially answer your question, I know that only the strongest slowing effect applies if many slows are dealt to an enemy. If a longer lasting, weaker slow is applied at the same time, then when the stronger effect ends, the weaker will persist until it's duration is up.

Ex. two slows, one of 80% for 3 seconds, and another of 40% for 6 seconds are applied at the same time. The following will occur:

- 80% for the first 3 seconds
- 40% for the next 3 seconds

Answer (score 0):

The only stat that passively defends against crowd control is "reduced duration of control effects by x%", some skills like DH's smoke screen or WD's spirit walk can break CC's.

Not everything can be knocked back but almost anything but treasure goblins can be slowed, snared, rooted, confused, stunned and interrupted (it's a special property some attacks have). Champions and bosses reduce CC duration increasingly over the difficulty levels. This does not affect CC's that are dependant on an area however like WD's grasp of the dead.